# Infinite nested objects in a treeview datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm new to databinding and datatemplate and i'm actually running into an issue as I want to bind object which can contains an ObservableCollection of objects from the same class.

Here is the actual XAML code :

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Node}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                 <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubNode}">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

as for the class code :

```
public class Node
{
    public Node(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Subnodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Node> Subnodes { get; private set; }
}
```

As you can see in my class code, an object can contain an infinite numbers of nested objects, unfortunately, I don't understand how I could manage to do something like this:

[image: Sample]

Is it possible to do such a thing and if yes, how so ?

Thank you in advance for taking the time to answer me, don't hesitate to  ask me more information if you need or to correct me if the words I use are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

template is simpler, actually

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Subnodes}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

don't forget to set or bind `TreeView.ItemsSource`

TreeView becomes infinite indeed when a node is added into its own Subnodes

```
var root = new Node("A");
root.Subnodes.Add(root);
```